# How can I fix density (vehicles/km) on a multi-line highway?

Tags: sumo

I want to run each simulation for each 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65 vehicles/km at a 3 way highway.

Some people say that the density setting is possible in the following address
https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_get_high_flows.2Fvehicle_densities.3F

But, I don't understand, how can I set the various fix densities in highway.

I tried to make various variables listed on this site, but I couldn't get  fixed density results.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to set up a circular scenario and insert a fixed number of vehicles. You will need a rerouter to let the vehicles drive in circles. This is implemented here: https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/tree/master/tests/sumo/cf_model/drive_in_circles. If you need a straight route you could use TraCI to insert a new vehicle every time some vehicle leaves to keep the number fixed.